# Executable Code in C++ Class

Tags: c++, class, execute

I need to execute code in a class definition in C++. I have a macro to add a method to a function pointer after the definition of the method. It expands to a call to std::map.insert that it needs to execute in the definition (think of how Ruby executes code in class definitions).
The class definition might look something like this after macro expansion:

```
bindings.insert(pair<char, ReturnType (*)(FirstArgument, SecondArgument)>("theFunction",&theFunction));
```

Would this execute in the definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a global, its constructor will then execute during program initialization.

See for example [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+global+initialization+order) and [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-order-fiasco) for how to make sure that `map.insert` doesn't execute until after the map is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't have executable code outside function body in class declaration. (if I understand you correctly).

At which point do you expect it to be executed?

Comment: My hope was to have it add the function to the std::map of method pointers after the method declaration. Might there be another way to do this? I might be able to do this after the declaration, but that won't work to well. It would work, but ruin the thing I'm trying to do.

Comment: The declarations are processed at compile time, whereas code is executed at runtime. I think you'll have to have the code elsewhere.

Comment: Ok. That will work in the end. I guess that makes sense, considering C++'s static nature.

Comment: Yes, so depending on how you want to use this information in the future, you may have a constructed global as Ben suggested or static array map populated at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in the constructor.